# Take a punch at this (or...identifying a boxer?)

Tags: england, 20th-century, photo-identification, sport

I have found the photo below amid a collection of family photographs. I don't think it's a relative, as we don't – to my knowledge – have any boxers in the family. But I am hoping to identify who this is. The only clue I have is that the word "Butler" is scribbled on the back. Is that perhaps the chap's name? I have no idea on a date, maybe early to mid 20th century? Presumably in England, but I suppose could be from anywhere.

Any ideas on who this is or how I might find out who this is?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ["B" page](http://www.boxinghistory.org.uk/blist.html) of "Find your boxing ancestors" on boxinghistory.org.uk lists several Butlers but only three with the first initial "G" (as his shorts appear to be monogrammed "GB").

The first of these, George Butler from Blidworth, Nottinghamshire, can be found on a ["Local Sporting Legends" page](http://blidworthhistoricalsociety.co.uk/37712.html) on the Blidworth Historical Society site. There's a photo on there which could well be the same man - similar build, face and hair, and the same "GB" monogram on his shorts. This George Butler was active between 1934 and 1947, according to the first link.
[image: George Butler, boxer]
(Image from [Blidworth Historical Society](http://blidworthhistoricalsociety.co.uk/37712.html))

Comment: I decided to add the image, with attribution and link. There's no obvious copyright notice etc on that site. Mods please revert if it's not appropriate.

Comment: Great find! The location is perfect as well.